# How to use NUnit Test Adapter with NUnit 2.6.3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit

I'm having this issue where I'm using NUnit 2.6.3 in my project, but after installing NUnit Test Adapter 1.0.0.0 (most recent version I can find) in Visual Studio Professional 2012, my tests still didn't show up in Test Explorer.  I realized soon that the description of NUnit Test Adapter states that it is compatible with NUnit versions up to 2.6.2, but it turns out I'm using NUnit 2.6.3.  Using NuGet, I can't find an older version of NUnit, and using Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates manager, I can't find a version of NUnit Test Adapter that supports 2.6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I needed to instead add the package "NUnit TestAdapter including NUnit 2.6.2 framework" to my project.  That fixed everything right up.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the reverse issue:
when using the nunit dll 2.6.3 my tests appears in the test explorer but fails for other issues, but when using the 2.6.2 dll, nothing appears..
I do not believe the issue with with your version based on this experience